# Output ctools_modal_form_wrapper() with translatable items in the form

Tags: javascript

i have translation strings already for this form.
if i output it with:

```
  return drupal_get_form('user_login');
```

then the translation works

but if i render it for the modal form then the translation doesn't work.

```
return ctools_modal_form_wrapper('user_login', $form_state); with translatable items
```

so how can i enable the tranlation for the ctools_modal_form_wrapper also?

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue for ctools modal_form and is in need of some more data / feedback to push the issue forward. The specific bug is called out here and appears to be related to the language header that is used in the modal form window:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2160293

There is a potential patch for this here:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2245123